# How would I turn this 2D drawing into 3D in Blender?

Tags: modeling

I'm not super familiar with Blender, but I imagine that creating a 3D room based on this 2D sketch wouldn't be super difficult. Any suggestions?

Thanks
Lars

[image: 2D drawing of room]

Answer (score 3):

Use your image as reference image in top view, create a plane, merge at center to get one unique vertex, extrude on X, Y or diagonally in order to draw the shape:

[image]

Extrude on Z:

[image]

Create some edge loops where you're supposed to have doors or niches:

[image]

Then extrude and remove the useless faces:

[image]

Cut off the doos:

[image]

Give your object a *Solidify* modifier with the *Even Thickness* option enabled:

[image]